# Couldn't find Project with 'id'= when trying to create a Task from Project profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through, strong-parameters

I have a projects model and a task model, however a task can have many projects and vice versa...so i created a relationship model between the two. Now from the project profile, i want to be able to create a task and automatically have it create the task and the relationship between the new task and the project it was created from.

However when i try to accomplish this i am getting the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in TasksController#create
Couldn't find Project with 'id'=
```

A user is on the Project show page and clicks a link to 'submit new task'.  I realize i'm not passing the project ID somehow but I can't seem to figure out how to do this because I'm using a TaskRelationship model to associate the task and the project (I'm not nesting the task in the  project in my routes).

views/projects/show.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to "+ Submit New Task", new_task_path, :class => "btn btn-info col-md-12" %>
```

From the new tasks view, I need to create both the task and the relationship between task and project.

views/tasks/new.html.erb:

```
<div class="container sign-in-register">
    <div class="authform">

           <%= form_for @task, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>

          <h3>Submit new task to this project...</h3><br/>

            <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

            <%= f.label :Title %>
            <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control' %>

            <%= f.label :Description %>
            <%= f.text_area :description, class: 'form-control' %>

            <br clear="all">

            <%= f.submit "Add this Task", class: "btn btn btn-info" %>
          <% end %>

    </div>
</div>
```

TaskRelationship Model (links tasks to projects):

```
class TaskRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :taskproject, class_name: "Project"
  belongs_to :projecttask, class_name: "Task"
  validates :taskproject_id, presence: true
  validates :projecttask_id, presence: true
end
```

Project Model:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, :foreign_key=>'user_id', :class_name=>'User'

  has_many :tasks
  has_many :taskrelationships, foreign_key: "taskproject_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :projecttasks, through: :taskrelationships, source: :projecttask

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :background, presence: true

  def related?(some_task)
   taskrelationships.find_by_projecttask_id(some_task.id)
  end

  def relate!(some_task)
   self.taskrelationships.create!(projecttask_id: some_task.id)
  end

end
```

Task Model:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, :foreign_key=>'user_id', :class_name=>'User'

  has_many :projects
  has_many :reverse_taskrelationships, foreign_key: "projecttask_id",
                                   class_name: "TaskRelationship",
                                   dependent: :destroy
  has_many :taskprojects, through: :reverse_taskrelationships, source: :taskproject

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :description, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
end
```

Tasks Controller:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @task = Task.new
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:taskproject_id])
    @task = current_user.own_tasks.build(task_params)
    if @task.save
      flash[:success] = "Your task has been created."
      redirect_to @task
      @project.relate!(@task) unless @project.related?(@task) # establish task relationship w/ project only if doesn't exist
    else
      render 'task'
    end
  end

private

 def task_params
      params.require(:task).permit(:title, :description, :user_id, task_relationship_attributes: [:taskproject_id, :projecttask_id])
 end

end
```

Task_Relationships_Controller:

```
class TaskRelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def create
  end

  def destroy
  end

  # I assume (maybe incorrectly) that i don't need create/destroy actions but do need strong params

  private

  def task_relationship_params
    params.require(:taskrelationship).permit(:taskproject_id, :projecttask_id)
  end
end
```

How can i get this correct ID passed so that the new task is created and the new taskRelationship between task and project?  thx,

UPDATE:

I've added the log for more detail

Terminal Log when trying to post:

```
Started GET "/tasks/new" for ::1 at 2016-04-15 19:55:54 -0500
Started GET "/tasks/new" for ::1 at 2016-04-15 19:55:54 -0500
Processing by TasksController#new as HTML
Processing by TasksController#new as HTML
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered tasks/new.html.erb within layouts/application (24.5ms)
  Rendered tasks/new.html.erb within layouts/application (24.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.0ms)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
  Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (2.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 192ms (Views: 185.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 192ms (Views: 185.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)




Started POST "/tasks" for ::1 at 2016-04-15 19:55:59 -0500
Started POST "/tasks" for ::1 at 2016-04-15 19:55:59 -0500
Processing by TasksController#create as HTML
Processing by TasksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"DGGG+zWPMbB7OwZz8oCVLB5O6sMfTe/Orj6KfeP6mrveOH0ImAP4aow0gufqefOdwsp8v4GDEt8ppJiL4CvQVg==", "task"=>{"title"=>"test", "description"=>"test"}, "commit"=>"Add this Evidence"}
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"DGGG+zWPMbB7OwZz8oCVLB5O6sMfTe/Orj6KfeP6mrveOH0ImAP4aow0gufqefOdwsp8v4GDEt8ppJiL4CvQVg==", "task"=>{"title"=>"test", "description"=>"test"}, "commit"=>"Add this Evidence"}
  Project Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
  Project Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Project with 'id'=):
  app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:8:in `create'

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Project with 'id'=):
  app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:8:in `create'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You'll need to pass the project ID to `TasksController#new` somehow.
One approach is to pass it as part of the request URL, something like:

```
<host>/tasks/new?project_id=<project ID>
```

This will make it available in the `params` variable of the request.

2) In your TasksController#new action, pass `project_id` from `params` to the view. The easiest way is using an instance variable:

```
@project_id = params[:project_id]
```

There is a philosophy of only passing one object to a view and here we're passing 2: @task and @project_id. I wouldn't worry about it but you might want to read up on form objects: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activemodel-form-objects

3) Add a hidden field on your form with the project ID. Because @project_id isn't part of the @task model, we'll use an input tag helper instead of a form based helper:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'project_id', @project_id %>
```

API doc: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag

Now the value of `@project_id` will be passed to the `#create` action as `params[:project_id]` when the user clicks on the `submit` button.

4) Change the params in `TasksController#create` action. `project_id` will be nested in with the `task` parameters:

@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])

5) You'll need to create your TaskRelationship relationship. There are a couple of ways to do this. I usually use `build`:

```
@task.taskprojects.build(project: @project)
```

so your `#create` action would look something like:

```
@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
@task = current_user.own_tasks.build(task_params)
@task.taskprojects.build(project: @project)
if @task.save
...
```

Comment: thx Alan - I think i'm following most of this except the first step.  where do i accomplish passing it in the URL?  would it be in the routes for the new task action?   (Also in this case, a task does belong to multiple projects so i probably couldn't take the belongs_to approach).

Comment: disregard Alan - i've just passed (:project_id=> @project.id) at the end of the new_task_path.

Comment: I've followed all steps...1) worked great. but 2) caused an issue:  when trying to access the new task page i now get 
NoMethodError in TasksController#new
undefined method `project_id=' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I've updated my answer to work with your many to many relation between Projects and Tasks. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller statement `Project.find(params[:taskproject_id])`, it looks like `params[:taskproject_id]` is nil. Looking at the code in your form view the params passed to the controller should be `params[:id]`. It's also not clear where `task_params` is defined

If you still are getting the error, check the params in the log output from when you submit your form and post them here.

Comment: thx Anthony - i've added my tasks params code (at the bottom of tasks controller).  How/where should I pass the params[:id] you mention?

Comment: In your `TasksController#create` statement, I've updated my answer.

Comment: it still doesn't find that ID...I'm obviously not passing it correctly.  I've updated with log output.